# How do I count leading zeros on both mac M1 and x86-64?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, x86-64, arm64, apple-m1

Originally I tried lzcnt but that doesn't seem to work on a mac. I'm working with someone who is using the apple M1 CPU which is ARM64v8.4

In this [arm document](http://115.28.165.193/down/arm/arch/ARM_v8_Instruction_Set_Architecture_(Overview).pdf) which list ARM 8 it appears clz supports using 0

> CLZ Xd, Xm
> Count Leading Zeros (64-bit): sets Xd to the number of binary zeros at the most significant end of Xm. The result will be in the range 0 to 64 inclusive.

The CPU we originally support is x86-64 which has _lzcnt_u64

Both instructions appear to return 64 if the value is 0. Specifically "0 to 64 **inclusive**" on ARM and the [intel site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=lzcnt&ig_expand=4425) suggest it too (and confirmed by my code)

However GCC says the below

> Built-in Function: int __builtin_clzll (unsigned long long)

> Similar to __builtin_clz, except the argument type is unsigned long long.

Can I safely use 0 or does this builtin use a different instruction? I tried on clang and the sanitizer stop the program and told me it is a problem which was surprising to me.

How should I get the leading zero count when I want to get 64 if I pass in 0 like these two instructions do

Comment: `__builtin_clzll` will compile to `63-bsr(x)` on x86 if you don't use a `-march=` option that includes BMI1 (or for some AMD, at least LZCNT without the rest of BMI1).  BSR leaves its destination unmodified for an input of 0, not producing `-1` or something.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not surprised you seen this first :P I just tried it again and confirmed `-march=native` was used. It still complained but I guess it's because this function can exist without the bmi/lzcnt flag. I'm not sure what I *should* do but what I did was write a zero check and stuck it in a define

Comment: [`std::countl_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If C++20 features are available, [`std::countl_zero<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero) solves the problem, and it's up to compiler devs to implement it in a way that compiles efficiently even for an input of zero.  (In which case it's required to return the number of value-bits in the integer type you passed, [unlike `__builtin_clzll`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html))

That's great in theory, but unfortunately they're faced with the same problem you are of using actual builtin functions.  libstdc++ just uses `x ? __builtin_clzll(x) : 64` more or less, which GCC doesn't optimize even when a hardware instruction is available that produces `64` for an input of `0`.  (See below C++ and asm code blocks.)

So in practice `std::countl_zero<uint64_t>` always compiles to multiple instructions with GCC even on machines like ARM64 always, or x86-64 even when `lzcnt` is known at compile-time to be available (`-mlzcnt` or `-mbmi`).  clang does optimize away the ternary.

---

`__builtin_clzll` will compile to `63-bsr(x)` on x86 if you don't use a `-march=` option that includes BMI1 (or for some AMD, at least LZCNT without the rest of BMI1).  BSR leaves its destination unmodified for an input of 0, not producing `-1` or something.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsr  (This was probably a big part of the motivation of defining the builtin that way, so it can just compile to a single BSR or BSF instruction without conditional branches or cmov on x86 long before lzcnt existed.  Some use-cases don't need to use it with zero.)

What's the goal here, portable GNU C++? Or perfectly optimized asm for a couple of compile targets with specific options?

You could try `x ? __builtin_clzll(x) : 64` and hope GCC optimizes that to x86-64 `lzcnt` when available.  **clang *does* do this optimization, but unfortunately GCC11 doesn't.**  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAOykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BfoHVtQL1jQTFkTFxibYNTS257SO9Yf1lg5UAlLaoXsTI7BxeDOnA4egA1Mi0AF4Qm9u7e7QCwJfXe6rzeyb%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%2BAMYAFAANTwTAAHduOSRgzJkQQRDEdgpDc%2BQlDUKDdC4fRSJQE9LH0HS4MgRZUGSRwBDkgBabigT2RKRNWKsgUJBAmAUeyNNoNKzXQXFCR2LwwosMx9w6eK/AgVwxj8IKQmmUpyj0VJ0nq5quoKeq%2Bg6uZbA0mp6u6UZPFaPQ6rqSYhoGCphh6PqgrNHpFtmCpFnPFY1j0UtMFU8ywO3Uhd33Q8OFUBJMUS7EDgMB1yPLDQ3r2CBj0saxSD2XBCBIa8/z%2BjxCPoYhga4eZeHvQT5mfEBf3LIFMQSABON9JCAjR0a/VH9E4CDSBYEBNwQy7eGu2D4MQ%2BHSBQ9CCOwiG8IgZmiJAMiuDMPhYVoygGPEpj9NczjGAIXj%2BKg4TRPWfdJPGvAZLk/cFKUlTXPUzTeG03T9MM%2BXYbLUnuHMqhLJsuzHOc3db34dzRHEbyHd8lR1HE3QgWCoxQp%2B8K9aiiAYrizIkpStKMuQLKcrygrkVgsbOgaprptyVrly2zqgu6wosjTlr8h6zIs5GuaukmNbRvsCaFvapbZsrgvG82%2BvtokXaLwOoKjpO9ct0g8Trtu%2B7HuAZBkBpLgP0%2B76rHC/78CISHlSCvYwZZuJgaBGG6a0BHSAQTAmCweJg8J8DeFJ8mLqg6nbFpuH98Rijy03dGuGxSQgUkLhKJq/w3swJAkHldGCe9zKMygUgDmrMKDs0wpveIjRZQJESiRIwiVSybCfHzGixA6JC33CLViYtMJcUlnxASCtMAiSMGJBWeApKOBVlBdWyBlInXIIIDSUE9Z6VYobYyJszKLAtkwKytkHJORcmbHyHlnbSFdood2AUQDSGesYKqEVohBxDvVJKLBkDJEqtlNATQFKJSYD%2BNKEdirmjKhVKqNVE410yC4ZcVc2olAbjnAamQq650Gm3bO1clYV1Ws3daSda6tx8e3daTcciFw2k0UuO0lj7S8neH4XD7KGElnFdMDB%2BCiIvudSm0EOAoLlFYp6pFPrYIYE%2BR4X1tGL0BivG8oNEFEWBpIXeT9HyH2PqfSg/dL4kzJhTO%2B4C4IISGchNCEAYG9LgfhNZgwUHYm5jVPBKkCGC0YmEUWcjxY8SoTLWhcsZZMKVqw%2BSikOGazkdrPhOkBEGQwEbHJpkzZiMtlIm2sj7ayAUV5JRsgVH%2BU9q%2BH2Wj/Y2EDvAfRYdODpWMaYwk5iVKqCsTY5KICwnJw8e4KJQRM4hJGkEgJ5KaVFCpctcuDBJrNHJcy1l6SW5TWSdyqY8Ts6dyyYdXJrl8k8SKSU66PAJkVNmRwN4AAlVMY8J5Txnm0xFf0AbLyhj08GW9lRmEGUhRG39yxcE3F%2BTE/hPxAjMJIBIGgNFEyvtM2%2BQ85mP1NaQF8v8LWSHRgkMwDr/CYiBJjLggRgGgKpuAxZEyzCxqqbDH1MkCHuMkEAA%3D%3D))

```
unsigned clz(unsigned long long x) {
    return x ? __builtin_clzll(x) : 64;
}
```

BTW, libstdc++'s `std::countl_zero` compiles the same way, presumably because it's written more or less like that.  (Probably with some `std::numeric_limits<T>` stuff instead of a hard-coded `64`).

```
# x86-64  clang 13 -O3 -march=haswell
clz(unsigned long long):
        lzcnt   rax, rdi
        ret
```

```
x86-64 GCC 11.2 -O3 -march=haswell
clz(unsigned long long):
        xor     edx, edx          # break output dependency for lzcnt on Intel pre-SKL
        mov     eax, 64
        lzcnt   rdx, rdi
        test    rdi, rdi
        cmovne  eax, edx          # actually do the ternary
        ret
```

Same story for ARM64: clang optimizes away the redundant selection operation to just `clz`, GCC doesn't:

```
# ARM64 gcc11.2 -O3 -march=cortex-a53
clz(unsigned long long):
        cmp     x0, 0
        clz     x0, x0
        mov     w1, 64
        csel    w0, w0, w1, ne
        ret
```

---

### Explicitly use lzcnt when available:

```
#ifdef __BMI__
#include <immintrin.h>
unsigned clz_lzcnt(unsigned long long x) {
    return _lzcnt_u64(x);
}
#endif
```

```
# x86-64 GCC11 -O3 -march=haswell
clz_lzcnt(unsigned long long):
        xor     eax, eax
        lzcnt   rax, rdi
        ret
```

(So really you'd want to use this `#ifdef` *inside* another function, with a #else using the ternary as a fallback.)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I guess I'm using `#ifdef` until optimizer catch up to the standard. I need well optimized in linux (release only) and it doesn't matter how optimized in debug mode (linux, mac)

Comment: Do you have any opinions on using a define like below? I never see `({...})` anywhere and I haven't used it much myself. It seems to correctly not call a function twice (-edit- maybe I should just make this as a function because I dont think I'll need to undef this. This is inside of ifdef's) `#define lzcnt64(X) ({ auto v = (X); v == 0 ? 64ULL : __builtin_clzll(v); })`

Comment: @EricStotch: That's a GNU C statement-expression that does exactly what my `unsigned clz(unsigned long long x)` inline function does (except without implicit conversion of the return value to `unsigned int`, or copy-constructing a temporary of the same type from it in case it's a class type that has a cast-to-int overload).  The value of the expression is the value of the ternary.  It's a statement-expression so they can avoid evaluating the macro arg twice, so it's safe for stuff like `lzcnt64(*x++)`.

Comment: GNU C statement? So it isn't standard C++? That explains why I never see it. Good to know. FYI I changed the function to your function immediately after I made the edit to the comment but I was still curious about that particular syntax

Comment: @EricStotch: I thought I replied to this, but seems something ate my comment.  It's a GNU extension, yes, to both C and C++.  And it's a "statement-expression", i.e. a statement that also has a value, not just a statement.  See the manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html   C already has statements.

Comment: *"libstdc++'s implementation to waste instructions on system where a good instruction is available"* - what do you mean by "waste" here? Do they not implement it as native single instructions when possible and use more generic ones? Is that what you mean by "waste"? Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I mean it compiles identically to my `x ? __builtin_clzll(x) : 64;`, because that's how it's written, which as you can see GCC compiles to mov-imm/lzcnt/test/cmov.  I guess I should make that clearer for people who don't click the Godbolt link.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm on mobile and Godbolt [*isn't exactly mobile friendly*](https://i.imgur.com/20W2CGL_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium) :')

Comment: Is there a corresponding bug report? All I see is 93071, which is not about the branch.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I haven't filed one, probably should have.  But if you have time, please do.

Comment: I don't know all the subtleties about the variants of bsr and lzcnt off the top of my head (I mostly remember that the internal representation of clz in gcc can be inconvenient). I sometimes file bugs for others when I feel I can do as good a job as them (or better), but that's not the case here.